# How do you deploy a Golang server with multiple api endpoints as a single cloud function?

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a `main.go` file that kind of looks like

```
func main() {
    connection := db.Connect()
    defer connection.Close()
    // db.ResetDb() // uncomment if you want to drop the db on go run main.go
    http.HandleFunc("/do-a", endpoints.DoA)
    http.HandleFunc("/do-b", endpoints.DoB)
    // ...
    http.HandleFunc("/do-z", endpoints.DoZ)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}
```

A database connection is established in the beginning using `db.Connect` any function in my codebase can access the database if needed. There are then several endpoints created with `http.HandleFunc`. Finally the server listens on port `8081` of my local machine.

All of the endpoint handler functions are pure functions. There is no internal state that would require the server to constantly be running which is why I thought maybe cloud functions could work. The only hiccup I see for cloud functions is the database connection that needs to be established before each endpoint call. I think this issue can be fixed with GCF as it can [cache objects](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations).

On a side note, *should* I be deploying my backend like this? Would it be better to just run it on a typical server that runs 24/7?

Comment: Use cloud run!!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use ListenAndServe in Cloud Functions.  The way Cloud Functions works is this.  It requires you define a function entry point for incoming connections whose socket is handled for you.  That socket endpoint has its own dedicated URL that you can't change, and it has a path related to the name you give the function.  You might want to review the documentation to see complete [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#sample_usage) for working HTTP functions.  See how you get a request and response object handed to you.

Because of the way this works, you can't run any sort of "server" - you just handle incoming requests that are managed by the system.  Typically, you give each endpoint its own deployed function.  If you really want to run an HTTP server, Cloud Functions is not going to be a good choice.  Consider instead App Engine, Compute Engine, or Cloud Run.

Comment: Would it be practical to have a single cloud function that routes to other functions? E.g. you could make an api call to this function with a route field in the header, then, using middleware, another function would be called based on the route info with the incoming `w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request`, and that would basically replace the several `HandleFunc`s I have in my `main.go` file.

Comment: I haven't seen this approach done before, so I wonder if it's a bad idea

Comment: I guess you'll find out if you try!

Comment: Haha, I guess so. It makes sense to me